# Visual studio - Who can tell me what is this and how can I do that?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

I don't know how can they write code and it auto break new line, who can tell me to setup it?

Comment: `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#-> General` (check Word Wrap)

Answer (score 3):

Check `Edit -> Advanced -> Word Wrap` OR `Ctrl + E, W` under default settings.

Works for all languages.

Answer (score 2):

This is the New Line symbol. it basically tells you that this is a completion line for the previous one.
If you want to disable it, it's in the General tab in the Text Editor Options.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> Tools > Options > Text editor > C# > Formatting > Wrapping

Check "**Leave block on single line**". Here is a snapshot of it

[image]